# Varnish Cache Redirect URL with Escaped Characters

Tags: url, caching, escaping, varnish

I have a Varnich config file which handles re-directs. Take for example this working example:

```
if(req.http.X-bare ~ "/faq/?$") { 
     return(synth(301,req.http.x-redir+"/faq-new?business=redir_mydomain.com&"+req.http.x-query+"#"));
}
```

This works as expected. But I can't get this to work if the URL I am trying to match contains a character that should be escaped, eg:

```
if(req.http.X-bare ~ "/faq\?foo=bar/?$") { 
     return(synth(301,req.http.x-redir+"/faq-new?business=redir_mydomain.com&"+req.http.x-query+"#"));
}
```

In the above case the match is not made and I don't see the expected redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this works:

```
if(req.url ~ "/faq\?foo=bar/?$") { 
     return(synth(301,req.http.x-redir+"/faq-new?business=redir_mydomain.com&"+req.http.x-query+"#"));
}
```

So using 'req-url' instead of 'req.http.X.bare'.